# Put file download image

Tags: 7, files

I'm using Drupal 7 and i've got 3 file field in content. I don't want see generic file, url file etc... I want spesific bg image on all my file field. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your theme's CSS to give every File Field a specific background image.  You would add this to your theme's stylesheet, looking for a "style.css" file in your theme folder.  The generic code for the background image would be:

```
.node-your-node-type .field-type-file {
  background: url("/sites/all/themes/yourtheme/yourbackgroundimage.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```